# Click each search result - iterate over elements found - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to write a piece of code in Python that would click every result of a search and within each seperate result download all the files.

I'm trying to write a for loop that would iterate over the search results, however when I run the code it's not doing anything, neither throws an error. I am a newbie to Selenium and **would appreciate if you could tell me where the problem lies, if it's the classes I'm using or the code itself.**

First I open the search result window:

```
driver.get("https://dane.gov.pl/pl/dataset?page=1&per_page=100&q=&sort=-date&format%5Bterms%5D=csv&types%5Bterms%5D=file")
```

Closing a popup window:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "footer-close"))).click()
```

My for loop:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-item ng-star-inserted")
count = 0 

for e in elements:
    e.click()
    for file in driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-star-inserted"):
        file.click()
        count+=1
```

I'm not entirely sure if I'm using the correct class names, since the code doesn't open any link but there's no error.

The code can be easily run if selenium and drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all since the locator has multiple class names you should use `css selector` or `XPath`, not `by_class_name`.
Otherwise this will give you 0 results, this is what you have currently

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".result-item.ng-star-inserted")
count = 0 

for e in elements:
    e.click()
    for file in driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-star-inserted"):
        file.click()
        count+=1
```

After clicking the `e` element another page is opened.
This will make all the rest of `elements` stale elements so you wil not be able to use them.
Also, `driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-star-inserted")` seems to be wrong, you are using a wrong locator here.
The correct locator there is `//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted']//h2//a` xpath so the code will be

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".result-item.ng-star-inserted")
count = 0 

for e in elements:
    e.click()
    for file in driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted']//h2//a"):
        file.click()
        count+=1
```

But you still have to solve the problem with stale elements - search results from the first page.
I would advise doing this as following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

#get the amount of search results
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".result-item.ng-star-inserted")
count = 0 

#iterate for all the result
for i in range(1,len(elements)+1):
    #get the n-th search result link    
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted'])[" + str(i) + "]")))).click()
        #inside the page get the links to be clicked
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted']//h2//a")))
    files = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted']//h2//a")
    for j in range(1,len(files)+1):
        time.sleep(10)
        file = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted']//h2//a)[" + str(j) + "]")
        actions.move_to_element(file).perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        file.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        count+=1
    #go back to results page
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough explanation. I was wondering how to get around the problem of leaving the search results page. I'm trying to work out the line with `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted'])[$i]",i=i)"))).click()` as there seems to be some quotation mark error.  Could you please tell me which part on the page you inspected to get this xpath? Thanks

Comment: Here I'm trying to get n-th search result on the main page since I have to get that element each time. Also, when getting back from the inner page I have to wait until the search results are presented again.

Comment: the element xpath is `(//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted'])[n]` where `n` is an index in the `for` loop. Sorry, I can't debug this on my computer, I even do not have python installed on it :)

Comment: All right, I get it. However I'm getting a syntax error for this line of code: `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted'])[$i]",i=i)"))).click()`. I guess `[$i]` here stands for `[n]`? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong if that works for you.

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry. The last `"` should be removed. See my updated answer. I hope now it will work. If still not I will give another syntax

Comment: Also it was indentation problem, just fixed it

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting a syntax error, this time however it shows an arror pointing `i=i` in the same line of code.

Comment: OK, I changed the approach, see if it works now

Comment: you solved this one, but I'm getting `'WebElement' object is not iterable` for the line `for file in driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='result-item ng-star-inserted']//h2//a"):`.

Comment: sure, its should be `find_elements_by_xpath`, not `find_element_by_xpath`. fixed that. Sorry

Comment: That worked, but with `file.click()` -> `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)`.

Comment: If so we should do there similarly to the search results. Moment.

Comment: `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` for the line `file.click()`. But, now, at least it gets to the first result.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. I added a sleep after the click, hope this will help. Let me know. maybe sleep should be longer, try 5 seconds if 2 will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this element is unclickable for python...

Comment: What exception / error do you see? try clicking with JavaScript like `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` in our case `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", file)`

Comment: I have added scrolling to the element. This should help even without clicking with JavaScript. Let me know if it is better now

Comment: Thanks for that. After the implemented changes, I get `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)` that points to the new line `actions.move_to_element(file).perform()`.

Comment: I have added sleep before getting the `file` element. Hope it will help. If do - you can reduce that delay after that.